# "Invalid input syntax for type double precision"

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM in NestJS with Postgres and I have an offers table in which I have a column declared like this:

```
@Column({
    type: 'float',
    nullable: false
  })
  totalTradingAmount: number;
```

When I query offers table using query builder, if I directly compare totalTradingValue with a number like this:

```
offersQuery.andWhere("offers.totalTradingAmount >= CAST(:totalTradingAmount AS FLOAT)", { totalTradingAmount: 40 })
```

it works perfectly fine but when I use TypeORM functions like MoreThan or Equal like this:

```
offersQuery.andWhere("offers.totalTradingAmount >= CAST(:totalTradingAmount AS FLOAT)", { totalTradingAmount: MoreThanOrEqual(40) })
```

it gives me error
"invalid input syntax for type double precision"

I have tried typecasting the both column and value to float

```
offersQuery.andWhere("offers.totalTradingAmount >= CAST(:totalTradingAmount AS FLOAT)", { totalTradingAmount: MoreThanOrEqual(40.0) })
```

but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, this works:

```
offersQuery.andWhere("offers.totalTradingAmount >= CAST(:totalTradingAmount AS FLOAT)", { totalTradingAmount: 40 })
```

If I understand correctly, if you interpolate the value you passed here, it looks like this:

```
offersQuery.andWhere("offers.totalTradingAmount >= CAST(40 AS FLOAT)" ...)
```

As you further mentioned, this does not work:

```
offersQuery.andWhere("offers.totalTradingAmount >= CAST(:totalTradingAmount AS FLOAT)", { totalTradingAmount: MoreThanOrEqual(40) })
```

I assume it is because when you do that, the interpolation would look like this:

```
offersQuery.andWhere("offers.totalTradingAmount >= CAST(MoreThanOrEqual(40) AS FLOAT)" ...)
```

Which doesn't make sense.

According to the typeorm docs, you'd want to use `MoreThanOrEqual` with `find()`, so perhaps this works?

```
dataSource.getRepository(offers).findBy({ totalTradingAmount: MoreThanOrEqual(40.0) })
```